# Java - возврат методом обьектов разных типов

Tags: классы, generics

Есть метод который возвращает юзера , но сам юзер это абстрактный класс, как в данной ситуации вернуть реальный класс (Админ или Ментор или Студент) , чтобы была возможность выполнять индивидуальные методы каждого из классов?

```
public User getUserByStatus(String status) {

    if(status.equals("admin")){
        return new Admin();
    }
    if(status.equals("mentor")){
        return new Mentor();
    }
    if(status.equals("student")){
        return new Student();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Либо пересматривать дизайн ваших классов, либо даункастить к нужному типу.

Comment: Забубень вместо 'public User' 'public Object'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо реализовать индивидуальные методы `Admin, Student, Mentor` в виде абстрактных методов класса `User` - если это не получается, то у вас что-то не так с дизайном классов.

**Update**

> Дело в том, что Студент к примеру будет иметь метод , который не будет иметь Ментор, зачем тогда его декларировать в абстрактном классе? Если выполнять его будет только Студент

Можно придумать такую конструкцию:

```
abstract class User {
    abstract boolean hasStudentRole();
    abstract void teach();
}

class Student extends User {
    boolean hasStudentRole() {return true;}
    void teach() {}  //пусто, студент не может учить
}

class Mentor extends User {
    boolean hasStudentRole() {return false;}
    void teach() { System.out.print("Teaching";} 
}
```

ну и т.д.

```
   User user=getUserByStatus(status);
   if(user.hasAdminRole())
       user.administrate();
   if(user.hasMentorRole())
       user.teach();
```

Comment: Дело в  том, что Студент к примеру будет иметь метод , который не будет иметь Ментор, зачем тогда его декларировать в абстрактном классе? Если выполнять его будет только Студент

Comment: Посмотрите на апдейт